# I can't find Global.asax, how to handle Application_Error in webform 4.5 in startup class?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I've working on upgrading an ASP.NET webform **3.5** website to **4.5** app. In the older version, the global error handling mechanism are located in the **Global.asax** file.

**Project > Add > Add New Item >...** I couldn't find Global.asax in the list. of templates. Instead, I see a all the way to the bottom of the solution a file called **Startup** with the following markups.

```
public partial class Startup {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

Is this file that replaced Global.asax file? If so, how to handle the global error?

Thanks for helping

## EDIT

Even when researching, it seems like the template is just not there.
[image]

Here are the steps I followed to create my project

## STEP 1

[image]

## Step 2

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `Global Application Class` located under the `Web` templates. That will create a file named by default as `Global.asax`

[image]

Comment: please see the picture that I just added. May be I should just import one from the older solution.

Comment: Nothing in the Web folder? Are you sure your project is web application 4.5 with web forms? I doubt it tbo. Create a new empty web app in 4.5 and check whether you can find it. Maybe you're missing something in VS

Comment: Please see the steps I followed to create my new application. It was not en empty solution. I wanted to take advantages of the existing code to help me with Identity.

Comment: I'm not getting through am I? :) The only reason to create an empty application is to check if you can add global.asax. If not, then there is a problem with VS and you should reinstall. If yes, then you have not created the original web application properly and you should either redo it or import a global.asax from the new empty web app.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using VS2015. I am using VS2017, and the situation is the same. Working on legacy code with legacy instructions requires some research into how things have changed and been renamed or deprecated.

I must use the same 2 step process for using the template that was formally titled `ASP.NET Empty Web Application` project. It is now titled `ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)` with subsequent dialog window to specify the `Empty` sub-template type.

When I select the `Empty` sub-template type with the checkbox for `Add folders and core references for: Web Forms` unchecked, no Global.asax file is created. When that checkbox is checked a Global.asax file is created.

**When a Global.asax is already present in a solution the `Global Application Class` template is not displayed in the Add New Item dialog box.** Delete the existing Global.asax file from the solution and the template will once again show up for selection.